# Mutually affected Vue js watch functions trigger infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've made multiple Vue watch fucntions affected each other.
But It doesn't seem to operate as I intended.

When a user tab 'vinput01' and change, vinput02 change under only vinput01 functions. And When a user tab 'vinput02' and change value, 'vinput02' change only under vinput02 functions.

But now, my Code trigger infinite loop.
Changing 'vinput01' affects 'vinput02' and 'vinput02' affects 'vinput01' at the same time.

Here is my Code.
How can I avoid this problem??

```
data () {
  return {
   vinput01: '',
   vinput02: '',
  }
},
watch: {
 vinput01: function(_val) {
 this.vinput02 = _val *1.1
},
 vinput02: function(_val) {
 this.vinput01 = _val / 1.1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have one property which is the 'source of truth'.  Your problem really is that you have two values competing for this.  To do this you can set one of your properties to be the primary value and the other as a computed property with a getter and setter. A good article about this can be found [here](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/adding-getters-setters-computed-properties), and in the excellent vuejs docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

Example code:

```
data(){
  return {
    vinput01:0,
  }
},
computed: {
  vinput02: {
    get: function(){
      return this.vinput01 * 1.1;
    },
    set: function(_val){
      this.vinput01 = _val / 1.1;
    }
  }
}
```